# inverse function theorem: $f$ is invertible(smooth inverse), then Jacobian determinant is not zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

[image]

---

Source: "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring W. Tu, p339, p68

For a proof, see  Rudin  "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" P221

But, if the map $f$ is invertible(has a $C^\infty$ inverse) in some neighborhood of $p$, then the  Jacobian determinant is not zero?

Answer (score 4):

By "invertible" it specifically means there is a *smooth* inverse. ("A $C^\infty$ map $f$... is *locally invertible*... if $f$ has a $C^\infty$ inverse...")  The cubing map $x\mapsto x^3$ from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to itself is *topologically* invertible with zero Jacobian at $x=0$, but the inverse is not smooth, specifically it is not differentiable at 0.

If there is a smooth inverse, then **yes**, this implies the Jacobian determinant is not zero, since the inverse function's Jacobian will be the inverse matrix, thus the original Jacobian is invertible (so its determinant is nonzero).